# Random forest and prediction

Tags: random-forest, prediction

I am trying to understand how Random Forest works. I have a grasp about how trees are build but can not understand how Random Forest make predictions on out of bag sample. Could anyone give me a simple explanation, please?:)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Each tree in the forest is built from a bootstrap sample of the observations in your training data. Those observations in the bootstrap sample build the tree, whilst those not in the bootstrap sample form the out-of-bag (or OOB) samples.

It should be clear that the same variables are available for cases in the data used to build a tree as for the cases in the OOB sample. To get predictions for the OOB sample, each one is passed down the current tree and the rules for the tree followed until it arrives in a terminal node. That yields the OOB predictions for that particular tree.

This process is repeated a large number of times, each tree trained on a new bootstrap sample from the training data and predictions for the new OOB samples derived.

As the number of trees grows, any one sample will be in the OOB samples more than once, thus the "average" of the predictions over the N trees where a sample is in the OOB is used as the OOB prediction for each training sample for trees 1, ..., N. By "average" we use the mean of the predictions for a continuous response, or the majority vote may be used for a categorical response (the majority vote is the class with most votes over the set of trees 1, ..., N).

For example, assume we had the following OOB predictions for 10 samples in training set on 10 trees

```
set.seed(123)
oob.p <- matrix(rpois(100, lambda = 4), ncol = 10)
colnames(oob.p) <- paste0("tree", seq_len(ncol(oob.p)))
rownames(oob.p) <- paste0("samp", seq_len(nrow(oob.p)))
oob.p[sample(length(oob.p), 50)] <- NA
oob.p

> oob.p
       tree1 tree2 tree3 tree4 tree5 tree6 tree7 tree8 tree9 tree10
samp1     NA    NA     7     8     2     1    NA     5     3      2
samp2      6    NA     5     7     3    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
samp3      3    NA     5    NA    NA    NA     3     5    NA     NA
samp4      6    NA    10     6    NA    NA     3    NA     6     NA
samp5     NA     2    NA    NA     2    NA     6     4    NA     NA
samp6     NA     7    NA     4    NA     2     4     2    NA     NA
samp7     NA    NA    NA     5    NA    NA    NA     3     9      5
samp8      7     1     4    NA    NA     5     6    NA     7     NA
samp9      4    NA    NA     3    NA     7     6     3    NA     NA
samp10     4     8     2     2    NA    NA     4    NA    NA      4
```

Where `NA` means the sample was in the training data for that tree (in other words it was not in the OOB sample).

The mean of the non-`NA` values for each row gives the the OOB prediction for each sample, for the *entire forest*

```
> rowMeans(oob.p, na.rm = TRUE)
 samp1  samp2  samp3  samp4  samp5  samp6  samp7  samp8  samp9 samp10 
  4.00   5.25   4.00   6.20   3.50   3.80   5.50   5.00   4.60   4.00
```

As each tree is added to the forest, we can compute the OOB error up to an including that tree. For example, below are the cummulative means for each sample:

```
FUN <- function(x) {
  na <- is.na(x)
  cs <- cumsum(x[!na]) / seq_len(sum(!na))
  x[!na] <- cs
  x
}
t(apply(oob.p, 1, FUN))

> print(t(apply(oob.p, 1, FUN)), digits = 3)
       tree1 tree2 tree3 tree4 tree5 tree6 tree7 tree8 tree9 tree10
samp1     NA    NA  7.00  7.50  5.67  4.50    NA   4.6  4.33    4.0
samp2      6    NA  5.50  6.00  5.25    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA
samp3      3    NA  4.00    NA    NA    NA  3.67   4.0    NA     NA
samp4      6    NA  8.00  7.33    NA    NA  6.25    NA  6.20     NA
samp5     NA     2    NA    NA  2.00    NA  3.33   3.5    NA     NA
samp6     NA     7    NA  5.50    NA  4.33  4.25   3.8    NA     NA
samp7     NA    NA    NA  5.00    NA    NA    NA   4.0  5.67    5.5
samp8      7     4  4.00    NA    NA  4.25  4.60    NA  5.00     NA
samp9      4    NA    NA  3.50    NA  4.67  5.00   4.6    NA     NA
samp10     4     6  4.67  4.00    NA    NA  4.00    NA    NA    4.0
```

In this way we see how the prediction is accumulated over the N trees in the forest up to a given iteration. If you read across the rows, the right-most non-`NA` value is the one I show above for the OOB prediction. That is how traces of OOB performance can be made - a RMSEP can be computed for the OOB samples based on the OOB predictions accumulated cumulatively over the N trees.

Note that the R code shown is not take from the internals of the randomForest code in the **randomForest** package for R - I just knocked up some simple code so that you can follow what is going on once the predictions from each tree are determined.

It is because each tree is built from a bootstrap sample and that there are a large number of trees in a random forest, such that each training set observation is in the OOB sample for one or more trees, that OOB predictions can be provided for all samples in the training data.

I have glossed over issues such as missing data for some OOB cases etc, but these issues also pertain to a single regression or classification tree. Also note that each tree in a forest uses only `mtry` randomly-selected variables.

Comment: Great answer Gavin! When you write `"To get predictions for the OOB sample, each one is passed down the current tree and the rules for the tree followed until it arrives in a terminal node"`, do you have a simple explanation of what the `rules for the tree` are? And do I understand `sample` as a row correctly if I understand that samples are `groups` of observations that trees divide the data in?

Comment: @user1665355 I presumed you understood how regression or classification trees were built? The trees in RF are no different (except perhaps in stopping rules). Each tree splits the training data into groups of samples with similar "values" for the response. The variable and split location (e.g. pH > 4.5) that best predicts (i.e. minimises "error") forms the first split or rule in the tree. Each branch of this split is then considered in turn and new splits/rules are identified that minimise the "error" of the tree. This is the binary recursive partitioning algorithm. The splits are the rules.

Comment: @user1665355 Yes, sorry I come from a field where a sample is an observation, a row in the data set. But when you start talking about a bootstrap sample, that is a set of N observations, drawn with replacement from the training data and hence has N rows or observations. I'll try to clean up my terminology later.

Comment: Thanks! I am very new to RF so sorry for maybe stupid questions:) I think I understand almost everything that you wrote, very good explanation! I just wonder about The variable and split location (e.g. pH > 4.5) that best predicts (i.e. minimises "error") forms the first split or rule in the tree... I can't understand what the error is. :/ I am reading and trying to understand `http://www.ime.unicamp.br/~ra109078/PED/Data%20Minig%20with%20R/Data%20Mining%20with%20R.pdf`. On page 115-116 the authors use RF to choose `variable importance` of technical indicators.

Comment: The "error" depends upon what type of tree is being fitted. Deviance is the usual measure for continuous (Gaussian) responses. In the rpart package, the Gini coefficient is the default for categorical responses, but there are others for different models etc. You should avail yourself of a good book on Trees and RF if you want to deploy it successfully. Variable Imprortance measures are something different - they measure the "importance" of each variable in the data set by seeing by how much something changes when that variable is used to fit a tree and when that variable is not used.

Comment: @GavinSimpson can you please confirm that the bootstrap sample size is defaulted to the size of the dataset? i.e., if I have a small sample size of (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`), my bootstrap sample could be (`1`, `2`, `2`, `5`, `5`) and my OOB sample would be (`3`, `4`)?